# Documenting inline functions and pure virtual functions with QDoc

Tags: qt

I'm new to [QDoc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qdoc/) and I'm trying to figure out if I prefer it over Doxygen. There's one thing that annoys be.

QDoc will only look through `*.cpp` files for `/*!`-style comments, so I can't document inline functions and pure virtual functions.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`\fn`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/13-qdoc-commands-topics.html#fn-function) command to refer to a function. For your two cases, put something like this in a `.cpp` file:

```
/*!
 * \fn void AbstractClass::pureVirtualMethod()
 *
 * Some info here...
 */

/*!
 * \fn void inlineFunction()
 *
 * Some info here...
 */
```